# Give one user read-only access to ECR repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

How can I give `a_user` read-only access (i.e. no permission to Push) and `b_user` is not banned?

**What I have done so far:**

- Added my AWS access + secret key with `aws configure`
- Made an ECR repo and did the `aws ecr get-login ...` command to get my login
- Added a permission that does:

  `Deny`, Principal: `my_principal_id`, IAM: `a_user`, `Push`
- Tried docker Push and it explicitly denies me despite being `b_user` (permission only bans `a_user`?)

Comment: b_user needs an explicit allow.

Comment: @jordanm I just tried that but doesn't work

Comment: Is this a question? It looks like a series of statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That may be better achieved through **IAM Policy for the User** instead of doing it on the ECR repo level.

Try this as a IAM policy for `a_user` (*read-only*):

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ecr:Get*",
                    "ecr:List*",
                    "ecr:Describe*",
                    "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                    "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/test"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this as a policy for `b_user` (*read-write*):

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ecr:*"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/test"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: AWS now has documented the policies for various use cases here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html